# import Swift non view controller class in obj c in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to import a Swift 3 class in ObjC but I am not able to do it for some reasons. The class is not a UIViewController class and the solutions which I found is perfectly working for View Controller classes but not for Model class. Can anyone help?

```
open class UserDetails: JSONEncodable {
    public var id: Int64?
    public var usertoken: String?
    public var firstName: String?
    public var lastName: String?
    public var email: String?
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Swift class to be visible in Objective-C, it has to be a `NSObject` subclass. Also, the types have to be Objective-C compatible (e.g. optional numeric types like `Int64?` can't be represented in Objective-C). It has to be non-optional or make it a `NSNumber`.

See [Writing Swift Classes and Protocols with Objective-C Behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH5-ID86) in *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C.*

---

FYI, I know you asked about Swift 3, but if writing Swift 4, make sure to use `@objcMembers`:

```
@objcMembers
open class UserDetails: NSObject, JSONEncodable {
    public var id: Int64 = 0
    public var usertoken: String?
    public var firstName: String?
    public var lastName: String?
    public var email: String?
    ...
}
```

Or if only some of these need to be available from Objective-C, just designate the individual properties/methods with `@objc` qualifier.

Comment: Thanks a lot but for swift3 when I just made UserDetails subclass of NSObject and added @ObjC it worked.